# Big Oh Notation Proof

Tags: algorithm, complexity-theory, big-o

The question is to prove that

- f(n) = 4n<sup>5</sup> - 17n<sup>4</sup> - 33n<sup>3</sup> - 13n<sup>2</sup>

is in Θ(n<sup>5</sup>)

What I tried to do what split up 4n<sup>5</sup> into two separate constants (2n<sup>5</sup> + 2n<sup>5</sup>) and make that whole equation greater than or equal to 2n<sup>5</sup> and got C = 2, N >= 6.

I'm unsure if I'm right and I'm still quite unsure how to actually prove that function is in Θ(n<sup>5</sup>). I hope someone can come along and help me solve this and what steps to take in order to prove other Big Oh notation problems.

Thank you for the help guys!

Comment: Actually, you just need to look into the definition. 1: For any natural number, f(n) <= 4n^5 (since all other terms are negative). 2. For n >= 10, n^5 <= f(n) (for n = 10 all lower-order terms will at most take ~2n^5 from the first term).

Comment: This is better suited for either [cs.se], or [math.se].

Comment: What kind of rules do you know for Landau notation so far? Derivative rules? Limit rules? Or is it definitions only so far?

Comment: On wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation.  You could prove that according to the definition of big-O notation.

Comment: Right now, just definitions

Answer (score 4):

#### f(n) ∈ Θ(g(n)) *(more general)*:

We have to show that there exists positive `M` and `N` such that

```
g(n) * M <= f(n) <= g(n) * N
```

for large enough `n`s. In this case, that's

```
M * n5 <= 4n5 - 17n4 - 33n3 - 13n2 <= N * n5
```

Divide by `n5`:

```
M <= 4 - 17(1/n) - 33(1/n2) - 13(1/n3) <= N
```

For large `n`s, we'll be left with

```
M <= 4 - ε <= N
```

We can pick `M = 3` and `N = 4`.

---

#### f(n) ∈ O(g(n)) *(more specific)*:

This actually follows from the result above, but we can provide a specific proof as well.

We have to show that there exists a positive `N` such that

```
|f(n)| <= g(n) * N
```

for large enough `n`s. In this case, that's

```
|4n5 - 17n4 - 33n3 - 13n2| <= N * n5
```

Divide by `n5`:

```
4 - 17(1/n) - 33(1/n2) - 13(1/n3) <= N
```

For large `n`s, we'll be left with

```
4 - ε <= N
```

We can pick `N = 4`.

---

**Reference:**

- [Family of Bachmann–Landau notations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Family_of_Bachmann.E2.80.93Landau_notations)

Comment: We only have to show `|f(n)| <= |g(n)| * N`, the other side is for `f = Omega(g)`.  You proved that `f = Theta(g)` which is stronger that `f = O(g)`.

Comment: @gongzhitaao I thought Θ was bounded both above and below. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Family_of_Bachmann.E2.80.93Landau_notations

Comment: I am only looking for Big-Oh, not Theta.

Comment: @Matt Then you only need to prove the right side, i.e., `|f(n)| <= |g(n)| * N`.

Comment: @arshajii Yes.  I agree with that :D.  But OP asks for Big-O.

Comment: @Matt But your question asks for Θ and not for O…

Comment: Actually sorry, I made a mistake. Yes I am trying to find Θ. Sorry about the confusion guys.

Comment: @Matt I included both, see the edit.

Comment: @arshajii thank you for the edit. I see that you wrote 4n5 + 17n4 + 33n3 - 13n2. May I ask why you changed the signs from negative to positive for n^4 and n^3 and left n^2? And when we find the values of M and N, how can we actually prove that the function is an element of big theta of n^5? Thank you again for the responses!

Comment: @Matt That was a typo on my part. I fixed it above.

Comment: @arshajii Thanks, I was also wondering what the 4 - ε was for? And how can we actually prove that the function is an element of big theta of n^5 once we find the M  /  N values? Thank you sir.

Comment: @Matt The ε just consolidates the other terms, i.e. it's a very small positive number. As for your second question: the existence of the M and N values is proof in and of itself.